# Alternatives to System.arraycopy when destination array differs on size

Tags: java, arrays, copy, clone

In a previous question [Why clone() is the best way for copying arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145826/why-clone-is-the-best-way-for-copying-arrays) @procrastinator demonstrates that given an array, `original.clone()` is in average two times faster than `System.arraycopy(original, 0, destination, 0, length)`

However I have noticed that when using the `clone` method it is not possible to modify the length of the destination array, nor copy only a portion of the array. Using `System.arraycopy` I would do:

**New array with extra positions**

```
int[] original = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
int originalSize = original.length;
int newSize = originalSize + 1;
int[] destination = new int[newSize];

System.arraycopy(original, 0, destination, 0)
destination[newSize - 1] = newValue;
```

**New array with less positions**

```
int[] original = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
int originalSize = original.length;
int newSize = originalSize - 1;
int[] destination = new int[newSize];

System.arraycopy(original, 1, destination, 0)
```

(Notice that the arrays in the example are small for the sake of clarity but in the real case they are bigger)

Is there a way to achieve a similar performance to `clone` in any of the scenarios? Or in these cases we must use the `System.arraycopy` method?

### **EDIT1 :**

As suggested by @aUserHimself I have tried (without any success) to measure the performance of the `System.arraycopy` against the `Stream` interface. Below I provide the Benchmark code and its results:

```
@Benchmark
public int[] SystemArraycopySmaller() {
    final int length = this.size;
    int[] destination = new int[length / 2];
    System.arraycopy(this.original, 0, destination, 0, length / 2);
    return destination;
}

@Benchmark
public int[] StreamArraycopySmaller() {
    final int length = this.size;
    int[] destination = Arrays.stream(this.original).filter(i -> i < length / 2).toArray();
    return destination;
}

@Benchmark
public int[] SystemArraycopyBigger() {
    final int length = this.size;
    int[] destination = new int[length * length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(this.original, 0, destination, i * length, length);
    }
    return destination;
}

@Benchmark
public int[] StreamArraycopyBigger() {
    int[] destination = Arrays.stream(this.original).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(this.original).map(j -> j)).toArray();
    return destination;
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                               (size)   Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopyBigger    10000  thrpt   10        ≈ 0             ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopyBigger     1000  thrpt   10        ≈ 0             ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopyBigger      100  thrpt   10     11,997 ±    0,002  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopyBigger       10  thrpt   10    608,899 ±    8,975  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopyBigger        1  thrpt   10   6373,457 ±  313,626  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopySmaller   10000  thrpt   10     36,692 ±    0,728  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopySmaller    1000  thrpt   10    328,875 ±    2,259  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopySmaller     100  thrpt   10   2141,368 ±    8,832  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopySmaller      10  thrpt   10   9018,659 ±  118,933  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.StreamArraycopySmaller       1  thrpt   10  12954,709 ±  114,621  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopyBigger    10000  thrpt   10        ≈ 0             ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopyBigger     1000  thrpt   10        ≈ 0             ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopyBigger      100  thrpt   10    161,004 ±    1,361  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopyBigger       10  thrpt   10  10039,397 ±  123,553  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopyBigger        1  thrpt   10  42539,869 ± 1965,589  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopySmaller   10000  thrpt   10    399,816 ±    6,503  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopySmaller    1000  thrpt   10   3189,271 ±  117,936  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopySmaller     100  thrpt   10  22533,102 ±  183,870  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopySmaller      10  thrpt   10  45577,443 ± 1656,788  ops/s
SampleBenchmark.SystemArraycopySmaller       1  thrpt   10  41657,519 ±  183,266  ops/s
```

Does anyone know about any other possible approach?

### **EDIT2 :**

I have updated the benchmark codes and results with the suggested modifications to make the comparison even. However, for the bigger experimentation there is some error (probably due to the heap size I suppose) and for the smaller experimentation the `Arraycopy` still outperforms the `Stream` one. **So I suppose there is no better way to copy arrays when the destination differs on size than using `arraycopy`**.

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks. See my updated question

Comment: I would say no, there is no way to achieve similar performance to `clone`. There is also `Arrays.copyOf` but it just uses `arraycopy` internally.

Comment: Of course if your performance hotspot is in copying arrays, maybe you're using the wrong language for the job?

Comment: @Kayaman It's not the only performance issue in my project but lets assume I currently cannot change language because I benefit from other Java utilities (the project has 100k loc)

Comment: Is it the most important performance issue in your project?

Comment: @Kayaman the array copies are on the critical path but I could also move them to a supporting thread and then synchronize only when needed. However I was just looking for a way to avoid that or, at lest, perform the copies as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to measure the performance against `java8`'s [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) as well, it can be useful when you need to filter out or add new elements to the `destination` array:

```
public static void copyBigArrayAndFilter() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] original = IntStream.range(0, 10_000).toArray();
    int[] destination = Arrays.stream(original).filter(i -> i > 1_000 && i < 9_000).toArray();
    System.out.println("Original size: " + original.length);
    System.out.println("Destination size: " + destination.length);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms." );
}

public static void copyBigArrayAndAdd() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] original = IntStream.range(0, 10_000).toArray();
    int[] destination = Arrays.stream(original).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(original).map(j -> i + j)).toArray();
    System.out.println("Original size: " + original.length);
    System.out.println("Destination size: " + destination.length);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms." );
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I am not an expert myself, but your question is interesting and I just had the idea of using `streams` in case you have processing to do on the `original` array before it is copied to `destination`. (see `copyBigger` examples)

For `copySmaller` examples, we are doing different operations: you are copying the first half of the `original` into `destination`, I am copying elements that are greater than `length / 2`, requiring in my case a full iteration over the `original`. How would you implement this using `System.arraycopy`?

For `SystemArraycopyBigger` you are just setting your `destination` array size to be double the `original` one, but you are only copying `size` in the end. Notice that in my `StreamArraycopyBigger` the `destination` array has `size ^ 2` elements, not `size * 2`: for each element in the `original` array, we had an extra `size` number of elements.

The results may not change by much in the end, but please try this instead if you want to test equivalent operations and not compare apples and oranges.

Also, why not try bigger sample sizes as well, like `10_000` or `1_000_000`?

```
@Benchmark
public int[] SystemArraycopyBigger() {
    int i;
    final int length = this.size;
    int[] destination = new int[length * length];
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(this.original, 0, destination, i * length, length);
    }
    return destination;
}

@Benchmark
public int[] StreamArraycopyBigger() {
    int[] destination = Arrays.stream(this.original).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(this.original).map(j -> j)).toArray();
    return destination;
}
```

I am not sure this is what you want. But what I am trying to point out is: if you already have the array processed, there are little chances you can do better than `System.arraycopy`. But if you need to modify/process and only copy a part of it, `streams` might prove faster.

Comment: As suggested I have bechmarked against the `Stream` interface without any success. I am not very familiar with it but the results are quite poor. Could you check my updated answer too see if I am missing something?

Comment: **@CristianRamon-Cortes** You are benchmarking different operations (in terms of time cost and efficiency) and there are some extra steps in my `stream` examples that will be obviously more time-consuming than your simple copy. See the update above so that you get more accurate results.

Comment: I have updated the question with the new benchmarks and results. Although the `arraycopy` still outperforms the `stream` implementation I suppose there is no other way so I will mark your answer as accepted since it is the one that provides the solution to compare the `arraycopy` against the `stream`.